# jQuery AJAX upload function from plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I use the [Valums](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) AJAX uploader, but I'm wondering how I can use this as a function like `ajaxUpload(file)` where the `file` value is coming from an HTML file.

What I basically want to do is have 2 or more fields but as the plugin creates the iframe all the inputs will have the same name! That I can't access the value of them when the form is sent with AJAX.

Comment: I really dont get the problem. First off: According to the plugin website it does not create a iframe any more. Secondly: If you just want to send a form with a file upload to your server, why do you use your plugin at all. Just make a usual form and thats it. If you ment something else hit me up, it was quite hard to understand your problem. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can always send additional values, the plugin provided methods doing so. Check out the docs.

In case you don't want to use built-in methods, you can use jQuery $.post, to post the data of your form, you don't need to rely on the upload to send your additional data